# Accessing same-named COM-entities from .NET assemblies

Tags: c#, vba, interop, ms-office, powerpoint

I've got a tiny (I hope) problem again, and I don't know how to obtain access to some presentation properties provided by PowerPoint (however I don't even know how to google it or search it at the site :( ) from C#. Let me explain. We can access a `TextRange` property both in C# and VBA, via an interop assembly and ms-office-built-in VBA editor respectively. It's ok, but this property contains two same-named entities - `Runs`. VBA allows to access it as a method and as a property (moreover, `Runs` property object insides are useful), but the property `Runs` in not accessible via the interop assembly, `Runs()` method can be accessed only (and it returns text run objects). I've digged in the interop assembly using .NET Reflector but I have not found anything related to the `Runs` property (though properties with different unique rather than methods names have own `get_Property()` and `set_Property()` methods). It seems that the interop assembly is missing the `Runs` property for `TextRange` interface. Frankly, I'm not sure. :(

Can I somehow obtain the access `Runs` property from C#? I'm not familiar with COM, etc, and I hope for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the Microsoft.Office.Core.TextRange2.Runs() property.  It is a property that takes two arguments, start and length.  Such a property is not directly accessible in the C# language, at least not [until C# 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/samng/archive/2009/11/03/com-interop-in-c-4-0-indexed-properties.aspx).  Only Visual Basic supports indexed properties right now.

The workaround is to use get_Runs() instead.

Comment: Thank you for reply. No, I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange, and it does not contain a definition for get_Runs(). :( Also, unfortunately I must note I use C# 2.0 and PowerPoint 2003.

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange has a Runs() method, it is not a property.  Beware that these TextRange classes are not identical, you can't mix a Word TextRange with a PowerPoint TextRange.

Comment: However Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange.Runs is also a property, and it's pretty seen from VBA. You have noticed it above in the answer. As far as I can see, I point the same entity both from C# and VBA. Sure, I cannot mix TextRange-s from Office and PowerPoint namespaces, but it is not necessary. I just want to get .TextRange.Runs.Count property. It is the only reason of the question. :) But... Probably can I somehow update the generated interop library when there's no source code? I would like to enhance it with something like get_RunsData(). Something like this I guess.

Comment: You know... Emmm... Nevermind, nobugz. I'll try somewhat another way, though I'm still confused. Maybe I'm wrong. Thank you. :)

Comment: VBA allows omitting the ().  Not C#, .TextRange.Runs().Count

Comment: I was wrong, and you were right saying "it is not a property", nobugz. :D It's my lack of knowing the VB syntax: I didn't know that a method that can be invoked with no parameters visually looks like a property! Wow... This made me confused! :D Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

In C# you have to specify where to start and where to end:

...

foreach (TextRange txtrn in txtrng.Runs(0, txtrng.Length))
{

if(txtrn.Font.Name =="Arial")
    MessageBox.Show(txtrn.Text);

}

.....

Comment: Thanks, but the issue was incomplete misunderstanding of VB(A) syntax where methods with all omitted parameters look like properties.